ccxt open position issue
I wrote below code for auto trading in future(open position calculate tp and sp) by ccxt library in python but I'm faced with this error:

An error occurred: bingx {"code":100400,"msg":" calc freezed volume is too small, volume: 0.00000000000000000000 ","debugMsg":""}

import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output 
import numpy as np
import ta


api_key = "xxx"
api_secret = "xxxx"

# اتصال به صرافی BingX
exchange = ccxt.bingx({
    'apiKey': api_key,
    'secret': api_secret,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',  # تنظیم حالت پیش‌فرض به فیوچر
    }
})

def get_balance_in_usdt():
    """
    دریافت موجودی کل اکانت به دلار
    """
    balance = exchange.fetch_balance()
    usdt_balance = balance['total'].get('USDT', 0)
    return usdt_balance

# دریافت داده‌های تاریخی بیتکوین
symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
timeframe = '15m'
limit = 200 
leverage = 10  # لوریج
tp_percentage = 6  # درصد تیک پروفیت
sl_percentage = 3  # درصد استاپ لاس

def fetch_and_plot():
    ohlcv = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe, limit=limit)

    # تبدیل داده‌ها به DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(ohlcv, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
    df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

    filename = symbol.replace("/","")
    # ذخیره داده‌ها در فایل CSV
    df.to_csv(f'{filename} {timeframe}.csv')

    # پاک کردن نمودار قبلی
    plt.close()
    plt.clf()
    
    # رسم نمودار کندلی با عنوان پویا
    title = f'{symbol} {timeframe}'
    mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style='charles', title=title, ylabel='Price', volume=True)
    plt.pause(0.01)

def trading_signal(df):
    # محاسبه 200-period EMA
    df['EMA_200'] = ta.trend.ema_indicator(df['close'], window=200)
    
    # محاسبه 12-period EMA
    df['EMA_12'] = ta.trend.ema_indicator(df['close'], window=12)
    
    # محاسبه Stochastic Oscillator
    stoch = ta.momentum.StochasticOscillator(df['high'], df['low'], df['close'], window=12, smooth_window=3)
    df['stoch_k'] = stoch.stoch()
    
    # محاسبه MACD
    macd = ta.trend.MACD(df['close'], window_slow=26, window_fast=12, window_sign=9)
    df['macd'] = macd.macd()
    df['macd_signal'] = macd.macd_signal()
    
    # شرایط BUY
    if (df['close'].iloc[-1] > df['EMA_200'].iloc[-1] and
        df['stoch_k'].iloc[-1] < 25 and
        df['macd'].iloc[-1] > df['macd_signal'].iloc[-1] and
        df['macd'].iloc[-1] < 0 and
        df['close'].iloc[-1] > df['EMA_12'].iloc[-1]):
        return "long"
    
    # شرایط SELL
    elif (df['close'].iloc[-1] < df['EMA_200'].iloc[-1] and
          df['stoch_k'].iloc[-1] > 75 and
          df['macd'].iloc[-1] < df['macd_signal'].iloc[-1] and
          df['macd'].iloc[-1] > 0 and
          df['close'].iloc[-1] < df['EMA_12'].iloc[-1]):
          return "short"     
    # در غیر این صورت سیگنالی وجود ندارد
    return "HOLD"

def open_position(symbol, position_type, leverage, tp_percentage, sl_percentage):
    """
    باز کردن یک پوزیشن مارکت (شورت یا لانگ) با لوریج، تیک پروفیت و استاپ لاس

    :param symbol: نماد جفت ارز (مانند 'BTC/USDT')
    :param position_type: نوع پوزیشن ('long' برای خرید، 'short' برای فروش)
    :param leverage: لوریج برای معامله
    :param tp_percentage: درصد تیک پروفیت از قیمت ورود
    :param sl_percentage: درصد استاپ لاس از قیمت ورود
    """
    try:
        # دریافت موجودی و محاسبه مقدار سفارش
        usdt_balance = get_balance_in_usdt()
        amount = usdt_balance * 0.1  # ده درصد موجودی کل به دلار
        print(f"Initial amount: {amount}")

        # تنظیم لوریج
        side = 'LONG' if position_type == 'long' else 'SHORT'
        exchange.set_leverage(leverage, symbol, params={'side': side})

        # دریافت اطلاعات بازار برای حداقل مقدار سفارش
        market = exchange.market(symbol)
        min_order_amount = market['limits']['amount']['min']
        print(f"Minimum order amount: {min_order_amount}")

        # بررسی اینکه مقدار سفارش کافی است
        if amount < min_order_amount:
            amount = min_order_amount  # اگر مقدار کمتر از حداقل است، آن را به حداقل مقدار افزایش دهید
            print(f"Adjusted amount to minimum: {amount}")

        # باز کردن پوزیشن
        if position_type == 'long':
            order = exchange.create_market_buy_order(symbol, amount, params={'type': 'future'})
        elif position_type == 'short':
            order = exchange.create_market_sell_order(symbol, amount, params={'type': 'future'})
        else:
            print("Invalid position type. Use 'long' or 'short'.")
            return

        # دریافت قیمت ورود
        entry_price = order['average']
        print(f"Opened {position_type.upper()} position at price: {entry_price}")

        # محاسبه قیمت تیک پروفیت و استاپ لاس
        if position_type == 'long':
            take_profit_price = entry_price * (1 + tp_percentage / 100)
            stop_loss_price = entry_price * (1 - sl_percentage / 100)
        elif position_type == 'short':
            take_profit_price = entry_price * (1 - tp_percentage / 100)
            stop_loss_price = entry_price * (1 + sl_percentage / 100)

        # تنظیم تیک پروفیت و استاپ لاس
        tp_order = exchange.create_order(
            symbol,
            type='limit',
            side='sell' if position_type == 'long' else 'buy',
            amount=amount,
            price=take_profit_price,
            params={'reduceOnly': True, 'type': 'future'}
        )
        print(f"Take Profit order: {tp_order}")

        sl_order = exchange.create_order(
            symbol,
            type='stop',
            side='sell' if position_type == 'long' else 'buy',
            amount=amount,
            price=stop_loss_price,
            params={'stopPrice': stop_loss_price, 'reduceOnly': True, 'type': 'future'}
        )
        print(f"Stop Loss order: {sl_order}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# حلقه برای به‌روزرسانی نمودار هر 5 دقیقه
while True:
    clear_output(wait=True) 
    fetch_and_plot()
    df = pd.read_csv('BTCUSDT 15m.csv')
    signal = trading_signal(df)
    print(signal)
    #if signal in ['long', 'short']:
        #open_position(symbol, signal, leverage, tp_percentage, sl_percentage)
    open_position(symbol, 'long', leverage, tp_percentage, sl_percentage)    
    time.sleep(300)  # 300 ثانیه معادل 5 دقیقه

